# Why is imagick SVG to PNG Conversion so messed up?

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, png

I'm trying to convert a simple SVG icon to PNG using imagick.

Here is what I get:

[image: SVG icon]  <<< before | after >>>  [image: Converted PNG]

Why is it so messed up? A lot of the svg icons I'm making are ending up messed up like this. How can I stop this from happening?

The php script is:

```
$svg = file_get_contents($svg_icon_path);

$im = new Imagick();

$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));

$im->readImageBlob($svg);

$im->setImageFormat("png24");

$im->writeImage('converted_icon.png');
```

I'm exporting the SVG icons from Illustrator CC

Comment: try readImage instead of readImageBlob

Comment: readImage results in `Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: no decode delegate...`

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original SVG file?

Comment: See my answer below @MarkSetchell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps to solve my problem were:

1. Export icon from Illustrator to .svg file
2. Re-open that .svg file in Illustrator
3. Save the .svg file again (modify something slightly so it can save)

When re-saving at step 3, Adobe illustrator significantly changes the svg xml, which seems to cause ImageMagick to convert it perfectly. Perfect so far anyhow.

But if I just export from illustrator to .svg and don't re-open and save it, ImageMagick messes it up almost every time.

This is what the SVG xml looks like when I first export from Illustrator:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 38.29 44.14">
    <title>icon</title>
    <path d="M35.06,13.76a0.71,0.71,0,0,0-.2-0.46L32.4,10.76a0.71,0.71,0,0,0-.51-0.22l-6.07,0a0.71,0.71,0,0,1-.71-0.7l0-2.07c0-.05,0-0.1,0-0.15,0-.83-1.56-5.9-6.35-5.5a6,6,0,0,0-5.55,5.06,0.68,0.68,0,0,0,0,.1l0,2.57a0.71,0.71,0,0,1-.71.7l-6.19,0a0.71,0.71,0,0,0-.51.22L3.49,13.22a0.71,0.71,0,0,0-.19.46L2.18,40.84a0.71,0.71,0,0,0,.71.74H35.62a0.71,0.71,0,0,0,.71-0.74ZM14.14,7.81a0.67,0.67,0,0,1,0-.09,4.9,4.9,0,0,1,5.08-4.23h0.09A5.11,5.11,0,0,1,24.1,7.7l0,2.16a0.71,0.71,0,0,1-.71.72H14.83a0.71,0.71,0,0,1-.71-0.72V7.81ZM6.59,11.7A0.71,0.71,0,0,1,7,11.58H30.92a0.71,0.71,0,0,1,.37.1l0.83,0.9H5.87ZM34.37,40.58H4a0.71,0.71,0,0,1-.71-0.75L4.49,15.26a0.71,0.71,0,0,1,.71-0.67H33.07a0.71,0.71,0,0,1,.71.67l1.3,24.58A0.71,0.71,0,0,1,34.37,40.58Z" style="fill:#231f20" />
    <path d="M24.54,15.53a1.91,1.91,0,0,0-1.91,1.89,1.75,1.75,0,0,0,1.49,1.85h0v4.9a5,5,0,0,1-5,4.52,5.17,5.17,0,0,1-5-4.41v-5a1.89,1.89,0,1,0-1-.09v5.08a6,6,0,0,0,6,5.76s6,0.05,6-5.84v-5A1.88,1.88,0,0,0,24.54,15.53ZM13.13,17.42a0.66,0.66,0,1,1,.66.66A0.66,0.66,0,0,1,13.13,17.42Zm11.29,0.66a0.66,0.66,0,1,1,.66-0.66A0.66,0.66,0,0,1,24.42,18.08Z" style="fill:#231f20" />
</svg>
```

And this is how it changes after re-opening and saving it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 38.3 44.1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 38.3 44.1;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#231F20;}
</style>
<title>icon</title>
<path class="st0" d="M35.1,13.8c0-0.2-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5l-2.5-2.5c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.2h-6.1c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7V7.8
    c0-0.1,0-0.1,0-0.2c0-0.8-1.6-5.9-6.4-5.5c-2.8,0.2-5.1,2.3-5.6,5.1c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1v2.6c0,0.4-0.3,0.7-0.7,0.7H6.3
    c-0.2,0-0.4,0.1-0.5,0.2l-2.3,2.4c-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.3-0.2,0.5L2.2,40.8c0,0.4,0.3,0.7,0.7,0.7c0,0,0,0,0,0h32.7c0.4,0,0.7-0.3,0.7-0.7
    c0,0,0,0,0,0L35.1,13.8z M14.1,7.8C14.1,7.8,14.1,7.7,14.1,7.8c0.3-2.6,2.5-4.4,5.1-4.3h0.1c2.4,0.1,4.4,1.9,4.8,4.2v2.2
    c0,0.4-0.3,0.7-0.7,0.7c0,0,0,0,0,0h-8.6c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7c0,0,0,0,0,0L14.1,7.8L14.1,7.8z M6.6,11.7c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.1,0.4-0.1
    h23.9c0.1,0,0.3,0,0.4,0.1l0.8,0.9H5.9L6.6,11.7z M34.4,40.6H4c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7c0,0,0,0,0,0l1.2-24.6c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7
    h27.9c0.4,0,0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l1.3,24.6C35.1,40.2,34.8,40.6,34.4,40.6C34.4,40.6,34.4,40.6,34.4,40.6z"/>
<path class="st0" d="M24.5,15.5c-1,0-1.9,0.8-1.9,1.9c-0.1,0.9,0.6,1.7,1.5,1.9l0,0v4.9c-0.2,2.6-2.4,4.5-5,4.5
    c-2.5-0.1-4.6-1.9-5-4.4v-5c1-0.2,1.7-1.2,1.5-2.2c-0.2-1-1.2-1.7-2.2-1.5s-1.7,1.2-1.5,2.2c0.1,0.7,0.6,1.2,1.2,1.4v5.1
    c0.1,3.2,2.8,5.8,6,5.8c0,0,6,0,6-5.8v-5c1-0.3,1.5-1.4,1.2-2.4C26,16.1,25.3,15.5,24.5,15.5z M13.1,17.4c0-0.4,0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7
    s0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7s-0.3,0.7-0.7,0.7l0,0C13.4,18.1,13.1,17.8,13.1,17.4z M24.4,18.1c-0.4,0-0.7-0.3-0.7-0.7s0.3-0.7,0.7-0.7
    s0.7,0.3,0.7,0.7l0,0C25.1,17.8,24.8,18.1,24.4,18.1z"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

We see a lot of complaints about ImageMagick's SVG support here. It seems that the library it uses for SVG conversion (librsvg) is somewhat buggy. You may have to tweak your SVG file a bit to work around whatever rsvg doesn't like. Alternatively, you may want to consider switching to a more reliable SVG rasterizer, such as Batik. http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on Batik. Will check it out.